# IntelliJ no longer makes configuration for Run

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, configuration

I was running tests just fine a few days ago. But, from some point onward, the Run button is greyed out and IntelliJ no longer makes configuration for Run. There seems to be no way to run the test. How can I address this problem?

[Run button being greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJOs6.png)

While I was searching online, I found this advice on adding proper Project compiler output and Output path and Test output path via Project Structure (as shown in screenshot below). But this did not fix my problem. Any tips on addressing this issue?

[Project Structure - Output path and Test output path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n4Ff.png)

By the way, when I tried to add Run configuration, it was giving me this message saying "Test Class is not specified". As shown in the image below, it didn't enable me to add the Test Class.

[attempt to create a Run configuration failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQmO1.png)

Also, I manually marked both `src - main - scala` as Sources Root and `src - test - scala` as Test Sources Root, but still didn't work. Then, I deleted .idea directory and re-imported the entire project. But then, I saw this message "[info] shutting down sbt server".

[now shutting down sbt server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Zft.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to create `Application` run configuration (instead of `ScalaTest`)? Did you try to compile/run/test your project via sbt?

Comment: Can you please let me know where I can check that the project is being run via sbt? I believe the project is being run via sbt, but not sure how to confirm it.
Also, for other similar projects I have `ScalaTest` was automatically generated when I opened them. I am not very familiar with what you are referring to (i.e., creating `Application` run configuration). How can I exactly do it and how do you suppose that this will solve the problem?